# Set HTML page title with js and pug

Tags: javascript, html, pug

Is there a way to add to the page title with js and pug, if I for example have a layout file with pug, which sets the page title to, say Aero -

And in the pug file extending the layout file, I want to append a string to that page title with something else, so it would display Aero - The added string.

Is this possible with some sort of interpolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
 title Aero #{addedString}
 meta(name='description', content="Aero" + addedStringDescription)
 meta(property='og:title', content= "Aero" + addedString)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked out, I didn't know what property='og:title' does, but I read some documentation and now I do understand :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the block append functionality of pug.

In the layout.pug:

```
html
  head
    block head
      title= 'Aero'
  body
    block content
```

In the template.pug:

```
extends layout.pug

block append head
  title= title + 'The added string'
```

Comment: Thanks, I did try this out, but it only shows the string from the layout file. I also checked for correct indentation in the file extending the layout file.

Comment: I would guess this needs to be block replace instead of block append